# Extract date from the name of the CSV file

Tags: r, date, extract, filenames

How can I extract `20151001` as date (like `2015-10-01`) in a new vector such that the new vector is:

```
  File Name Date
  Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv 2015-10-01
```

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? Are all filenames the exact same format?

Comment: Split on `_`, take 2nd value, format, ... show some effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sub`, match one or more characters that are not a `_` followed by `-`, capture the numeric part (`(\\d+)`) followed by characters until the end of the string.  In the replacement, we use the backreference (`\\1`).  After the string got extracted, we can convert to `Date` class with `as.Date` specifying the `format`.

```
as.Date(sub('[^_]+_(\\d+).*', '\\1', df1[,1]), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2015-10-01"
```

---

A compact option would be using `str_extract` with `ymd`

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
ymd(str_extract(df1[,1], '\\d+'))
#[1] "2015-10-01 UTC"
```

#### Update

If we need to extract the time,

```
t1 <- sub('^[^_]+_[^_]+_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})_.*', '\\1:\\2', df1[,1])
t1
#[1] "00:00"
strptime(t1, format='%H:%M')
```

Comment: Akrun, lubridate's ymd function gave me an additional "UTC" while in extracting the date, which I do now want. What Tensibai used "sub" function, worked perfectly for me. Thanks to both.

Comment: @ManojKumar  You can just wrap with `as.Date(ymd(..` and it will be fine.  I also showed the `sub` function, which you didn't mention at all..

Answer (score 6):

All solutions will be around extracting the date and then convert it with `as.Date(,"%Y%m%d")` to tell it the format.

First option with `sub` to extract the date:

```
file_name <- "Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv"
file_date <- as.Date(sub( ".*?_(\\d{8})_.*", "\\1", file_name), "%Y%m%d" )
```

Second option with `strsplit` as your file name seems separated by underscores:

```
file_date <- as.Date(strsplit(file_name,"_")[[1]][2], "%Y%m%d")
```

Other options has been given by akrun in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks Tensibai... just a quick question, if I need to extract only date from "Residential_20151001_0000_1.csv", i.e. 0000 as 00:00 (HH:MM ), how?  I tried: as.Date(sub( ".*?_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\2", file_name$FileName), "%H%M" )... But it was wrong code and produced NAs.

Comment: You extend the regex: gsub("(\\d{8})_(\\d{4})","\\1 \\2",file_name) and use as.POSIXlt to get a date time object with format "%Y%m%d %H%M"